# Using a img src prototype in a slider to change the slider image

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

Im trying to build a gallery modal slider.  So far I can open the modal with the correct image showing by using the targets src.  How can I use that same src property to change the modals image on a click or a next or prev btn?

html:

```
<div class="galleryModal">

            <div class="galleryModal__imgContainer">
                <span id="closeModal" class="closeBtn">&times</span>

                <img src="/dist/images/gal1.jpg" alt="modal main image" class="galleryModal__img current">

                <div class="galleryModal__controls">
                    <svg class="prevBtn modalBtn">
                        <use xlink:href="/dist/images/sprite.svg#icon-play3"></use>
                    </svg>
                    <svg class="nextBtn modalBtn">
                        <use xlink:href="/dist/images/sprite.svg#icon-play3"></use>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

JS:

```
let myImages = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery__img');
let modal = document.querySelector('.galleryModal');
let closeBtn = document.querySelector('.closeBtn');
let current = document.querySelector('.current');
let next = document.querySelector('.nextBtn');
let prev = document.querySelector('.prevBtn');

console.log(myImages);


//OPEN MODAL ON IMAGE CLICK
myImages.forEach(img => {
    img.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        modal.style.display = 'block';
        current.src = e.target.src;
    })
})

//CLOSE MODAL
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
})
```

Answer (score 2):

What i understood is, you have grid of images on click of image you need to show that image in popup and then on clicking next/prev button other images show display.

Check this working snippet [here](http://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/). Try changing you code with these sample snippet. You will easily achieve.

Hope this may help.

Comment: thanks for this, but I'm trying to avoid using a plugin I'm using this as practice in writing it for myself.  I have it so the clicked image is the one appears when the modal opens.  Just trying to work out the most efficient way of displaying the other gallery images on a click of next/prev.  Appreciate the help thou.

Comment: Ops. You didn't mentioned that in question. So provided my suggestion.